# Unwanted _posts structure after build

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have the current structure in my repository:

```
./_posts/2018-07-01-A-Post.md
./_posts/2018-07-01-Another-Post.md
./modules/A_Module/_posts/2018-07-01-A-Third-Post.md
```

all of the files above have this frontmatter:

```
---
layout:     article
permalink:  /article/:categories/:title
title:      A Post
date:       2018-07-01 12:00:00
categories: Announcement
thumbnail:  
author:     lipkau
tags:
 - Release
---
```

the `./modules/A_Module` is a submodule loaded with `.gitmodules` and the "A Third Post" is maintained in that repository.

Want I was going for, and expected as a result of this, is that all posts are shown in exactly the same way. But turns out I was wrong. This is the result in `./_site`:

```
./_site/article/announcement/A-Post.html
./_site/article/announcement/Another-Post.html           <--- all good so far
./_site/modules/A_Module/announcement/A-Thrid-Post.html  <--- why did this happen?
```

This is my *redacted* `_config.yml`:

```
# Website settings
title: AtlassianPS
description: A PowerShell community for Atlassian products
keywords: Atlassian,AtlassianPS,jira,confluence,bitbucket,hipchat,jiraps,confluenceps,bitbucketps,hipchatps,github,gh-pages
baseurl: ""
url: "https://atlassianps.org"

# analytics
## google analytics
ga: UA-XXXXXXXX-1

# Build settings
encoding: utf-8

# other settings
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->

markdown: kramdown

kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    disable: true
```

And here my `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "modules/JiraPS"]
    path = modules/JiraPS
    url = https://github.com/AtlassianPS/JiraPS.git
    branch = master
```

How must I change the files, so that I can maintain a post in a different repository, but to still have the same structure as the other posts?
I want the third post to show up, but not as `https://.../article/modules/A_Module/announcement/A-Third-Post` but rather `https://.../article/announcement/A-Third-Post`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

The fastest and easiest fix is to hardcode the permalink in your docs' front-matter. You are already specifying a permalink per doc, so this should not be a hindrance. However, since `modules` is a custom collection, you shouldn't use a variable like `: article`, you should instead hardcode it like so:

`permalink: /article/announcement/A-post`

Although you can use the `: categories` variable in the permalink, you still should not because this can be an array and not always string.

or (if not using URL rewrites:

`permalink: /article/announcement/A-post.html`

Comment: I don't want the directory to get ignored by git.
I want the third post to show up, but not as `https://.../article/modules/A_Module/announcement/A-Third-Post`
but rather
`https://.../article/announcement/A-Third-Post`

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I tried that, and nothing changed.

I also fail to understand why your frontmatter would differ from mine
(`permalink:  /article/:categories/:title`)

Comment: Is modules a collection? can you please paste your config file?

Comment: added to the OP